# White gaps in links border in Safari

Tags: hyperlink, safari, space

I have a link that looks like this:

Документи

And problem is that in Safari when "Документи" is underlined, letter "Д" and "у" cut line and there is small white space in link line.
How to remove these white gaps in link?

Answer (score 0):

### Remove the underline for all `<a>` elements

In CSS you could do:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

### Remove the underline for only Cyrillic class

Or alternatively for only Cyrillic links:

```
a.cyrillic {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.cyrillic:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykjhrzvk/) to clarify.

This removes the underline from the link. It's by no means perfect (if you wanted to retain the underline) but it at least solves the issue by removing it entirely. Of course, this assumes that your links are coloured somehow

### `border-bottom` underline

It is possible to get the result you want using the CSS `border-bottom` style as such:

```
a.cyrillic {
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.cyrillic:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And obviously on your HTML `<a>` element it should be:

```
<a href="#" class="cyrillic">Документи</a>
```

Here's another [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykjhrzvk/1/) to clarify.

Comment: I want my link to be underlined. I only want to remove white gaps, not the whole line. Is there a way to do that? :)